# Perl hash to json conversion?

Tags: json, perl, web-crawler

i have coded a crawler in perl to to get the url, title of the site and put it into a hash as following

```
   $VAR1 = {
      'address1' => {
                  'url' => 'dthree',
                  'title' => 'done'

                },
      'address2' => {
                    'url' => 'dthree',
                     'title' => 'done'

                  }
    };
```

then how can i convert it into json format .. im using MOJO::Json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first four lines in `Mojo::JSON`'s [SYNOPSIS](https://metacpan.org/module/Mojo%3a%3aJSON#SYNOPSIS) will tell you.

```
use Mojo::JSON;
my $json = Mojo::JSON->new->encode( $VAR1 );
```